# How to bend connection between 2 curves?

Tags: draw-mode

I want to draw lines on the surface of an object and then connect them. I am doing this by drawing curves. When I connect the curves the connection between them has sharp edges, which I don't want. I need something as the draw tubes in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SgkzU8vhCj0. How do I create  rounded edges (indicated in red) as in following figure: [image]

Comment: You may have your handles type set as _vector_. Try selecting the points you want (or the whole curve) then press V and select _Aligned_.

Comment: @ChristopherBennett this does not lead to the edges being rounded